# My Android AIR app shows white screen when TextInput loses focus

Tags: android, apache-flex, mobile, air, textinput

That's pretty much sums up the question. I have an AIR Mobile Flex App project in FlashDevelop that is using views to show content. Everything works fine, I can add a TextInput or TextArea to the stage, select it (Soft Keyboard shows up then), type some text. But when I press enter or change focus to the other element to hide the keyboard, the screen turns completely white except for the text that has been entered in the field.

Now it becomes interesting. If I rotate my tablet to force the screen to adjust, the content becomes again visible. Sometimes it doesn't even show a white screen, but rather a pitch black one that shows a blank preview when looking at the list of the running apps.

I cannot grasp the logic besides this behavior. It seems that somehow screen just doesn't want to redraw.

**UPD:**

AIR verison: 3.1

Tested on HYUNDAI SmartPad H-SP701G, Android 4.0.4

**UPD2:**

Tested on SANSUI ETAB 801VP, still getting the same effect.

Comment: It would nice to learn about your tablet details.

Comment: I'm currently testing it on HYUNDAI SmartPad H-SP701G, Android 4.0.4. I'll try to grab another tablet to see is the app behaves differently.

Comment: What is your top level component, is it by any chance a WindowedApplication? Maybe try another toplevel component?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your application configuration XML.
Check your  tag.
Entering value of "auto" or "cpu" should fix the problem.

```
<renderMode>auto</renderMode>
```

In my case I set direct and this was the cause of the issue. Using direct render mode caused the application to not work on HTC Evo 3D and Samsung galaxy s3. It did work on HTC Desire though.