# Flex custom layout behaves differently on my Android tablet

Tags: android, apache-flex, air

Failed to find a solution for my [previous problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15354929/my-android-air-app-shows-white-screen-when-textinput-loses-focus), I decided to implement my own soft keyboard using custom layout. What I wanted to do for keyboard is to be able to fit it smoothly into a variety of different screen sizes. So when the keys are overlapping the boundaries of the screen, the whole line is devided and positioned neatly.

Everything went as planned. I overrided `updateDisplayList()` to reposition the elements
 and `measure()` to assing correct sizes so when positioned in a vertical group, my layout would stretch it accordingly.

The problem arouse when I installed the app on my tablet. The positionings were all wrong. The sizes appeared to be a triple of what should have been.

I'm testing the app on my **SANSUI ETAB 801VP** (AIR 3.6.0.585, Android 4.0.4)

Below is the code for positioning:

```
override public function updateDisplayList(width : Number, height : Number):void
    {
        var x : Number = 0, y : Number = 0;

        for (var i : uint = 0; i < target.numElements; i++) {
            var element : ILayoutElement = target.getElementAt(i);

            element.setLayoutBoundsSize(NaN, NaN);

            var dx : Number = x + element.getLayoutBoundsWidth() + _gap;

            if (dx >= target.parent.width) {
                i = Math.floor(i / 2);
                x = dx = 0;
                y += getMaxHeight(0, i) + _gap;
            }

            element.setLayoutBoundsPosition(x, y);

            x = dx;
        }
    }
```

And measuring:

```
override public function measure():void
    {
        var indent : Number = 0, height : Number = 0;

        var next : uint = 0;

        for (var i : uint = 0; i < target.numElements; i++) {
            var element : ILayoutElement = target.getElementAt(i);

            element.setLayoutBoundsSize(NaN, NaN);

            var dx : Number = indent + element.getLayoutBoundsWidth() + _gap;

            if (dx >= target.parent.width) {
                height += getMaxHeight(next, i) + _gap;

                next = 0;
            }

            indent = dx;
        }

        height += height == 0
            ? getMaxHeight()
            : getMaxHeight(next);

        target.measuredWidth  = target.parent.width;
        target.measuredHeight = height;
    }
```

`getMaxHeight()` iterates over specidied range of elements, calculating the max height:

```
private function getMaxHeight(startIndex : uint = 0, endIndex : uint = 0x7fffffff):Number
    {
        endIndex = Math.min(target.numElements, endIndex);

        var height : Number = 0;

        for (var i : uint = 0; i < endIndex; i++) {
            var element : IVisualElement = target.getElementAt(i);

            element.setLayoutBoundsSize(NaN, NaN);

            height = Math.max(element.height, height);
        }

        return height;
    }
```

Am I missing something here? In my FlashDevelop the platform is set to AIR Mobile 3.1. Should I try to install AIR 3.6 on my computer to meet the results that I'm getting on my tablet?